# I've got this exception "ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My application works fine but this i have this in logs. I guess it's related to IntelliJ. If any one confirm me this

```
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData
```

Comment: This problem [was reported to JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122182) quite a long time ago, without a fix so far... Maybe you could comment and upvote the jira issue.

Comment: It looks like reason that there is no fix is that the person who raised the issue did not respond to the request for more information.  But judging from related Q&As, this is cause by something attempting to deserialize a serialized object in the clipboard that was placed there by Intellij.

Comment: Thank you guys,  i'm reassured now ...